# Calling Method from NSObject to ViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, nsobject

I am Calling a Method from Facebook's `FBrequest` class to my viewcontroller class 
Method has been call and I get value in `NSLog` also. 
But it doesnt display anything in simulator or device.Even connections in XIB is also set.
I dont know why this happens please help I am stucked from last 4 days.

I am Pasting my Code.

**FBRequest.m**

```
ViewController *objView =[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[objView MethodCall];
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)MethodCall
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 300)];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view]
}
```

Pls Help me

Comment: Have you actually presented the new view controller somewhere?

Comment: no in fbrequest i just alloc my view controller class. and the method also calls but there is no effects on simulator or device

Comment: Because you haven't presented the view controller. It won't show until you tell it to by presenting it via the -presentViewController:animated:completed: method or by using some already presented container controller's API to present it (e.g., calling -pushViewController:animated: on a presented UINavigationController)

Comment: P.s. I'm typing method/class names from memory, so please look up to verify the actual method names.

Comment: jason fbrequest methods are running on background and my i dont want to present my viewcontroller because it is already there. i am just calling these method from fbrequest to get response from there, to display a view only

Comment: Right but you create a view controller, don't present it, call a method on it that creates a new view and ads it to the _as yet unpresented_ view controller and question why you don't see anything. It is not already there. Based on the code you provided above, it's a new controller, you haven't presented it, so it's view hierarchy is completely divorced from your window, which is why you see nothing on the display.

Comment: jason its not a  new controller its the same controller i just want only that from fbrequest i get a response and it display that message on my the view in the same controller.

Comment: This code: ViewController *objView =[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; allocates a new instance of ViewController that is not presented.  This is what you are calling the MethodCall on.